# Sqoop incremental Import fail

Tags: hive, sqoop

I have the following table: mergetab in MYSQL.

```
id | name      | city        | rectime             |
---+-----------+-------------+---------------------+
 1 | Sidhartha | Hyderabad   | 2017-04-18 15:31:22 |
 2 | Saketh    | Bengaluru   | 2017-04-18 15:32:37 |
 3 | Sunny     | Mumbai      | 2017-04-18 15:32:57 |
 4 | Bobby     | Delhi       | 2017-04-18 15:33:15 |
```

I have inserted a record in it and it looks as below:

```
id | name      | city        | rectime             |
---+-----------+-------------+---------------------+
 1 | Sidhartha | Hyderabad   | 2017-04-18 15:31:22 |
 2 | Saketh    | Bengaluru   | 2017-04-18 15:32:37 |
 3 | Sunny     | Mumbai      | 2017-04-18 15:32:57 |
 4 | Bobby     | Delhi       | 2017-04-18 15:33:15 |
 5 | Madhavi   | Dharmavaram | 2017-04-18 16:57:09 |
```

Im trying to do a sqoop incremental import using the following command:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/mydb --table mergetab --username root --password cloudera --hive-import --hive-table mergetab --incremental-append --check-column id --last-value $(hive -S -e "select max(id) from mergetab");
```

Im getting the following error which I couldn't understand what is wrong with my sqoop command.
Error:

```
17/04/18 17:35:26 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments for import:
17/04/18 17:35:26 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: WARN:
17/04/18 17:35:26 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: The
17/04/18 17:35:26 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: method
17/04/18 17:35:26 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: class
17/04/18 17:35:26 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory#release()
17/04/18 17:35:26 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: was
17/04/18 17:35:26 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: invoked.
17/04/18 17:35:26 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: WARN:
17/04/18 17:35:26 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: Please
17/04/18 17:35:26 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: see
17/04/18 17:35:26 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#release
17/04/18 17:35:26 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: for
17/04/18 17:35:26 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: an
```

Im practicing this in Cloudera VM. Can anyone let me what is the mistake that I am doing here ?

Comment: Did you simply try to run that `hive -S -e "...wtf..."` command in a shell, and see what kind of junk it was generating?

Comment: I tried. FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'hive' '-' 'S'.   
But even without '-S', Im still getting the same error message.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code line `--last-value $(hive -S -e "select max(id) from mergetab")` is, hive will always print header/logging information even in silent mode, so last-value will always get value like -

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/Cellar/hive/2.1.0/libexec/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.3/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
5
```

you need to either write some twisted shell script to extract the last line or you can use beeline with `showHeader` and `outputformat` as shown below to just get the value directly assigned to variable

```
--last value $(beeline --showHeader=false --outputformat=tsv2 -e "your query")
```

Comment: I gave this in the lastvalue: --last-value $(beeline --showHeader=false --outputformat=tsv2 -e "select max(id) from mergetab")
Im getting an error message: 
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
17/04/21 12:40:22 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6-cdh5.8.0
Missing argument for option: last-value

Comment: That is warning I think. To make that go away, you need to set $ACCUMULO_HOME